# .htaccess redirection from non www to www but with a forced exception for a page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web

I am trying to redirect all visitors from non-www to www, which is currently done via

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^mysite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but a would like a forced exception for a specific page to redirect from www to non-www...

is `RewriteRule ^/?$ exception.html [L]` the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to prevent a page from non-www to redirect, you have to set the rewrite rule before the one that redirect.

The option [L] will prevent next rules to be checked.

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^mysite.com 
RewriteRule ^exception\.html$ exception.html [L]

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^mysite.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I hope this help you

Comment: works ok, but it does not force www.mysite.com/exception.html to go to mysite.com/exception.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

### Redirect www.mysite.com/exception.html -> mysite.com/exception.html  (OPTIONAL)

Only add this RewriteRule if you also want to redirect www.mysite.com/exception.html to mysite.com/exception.html.

If you simply only want exception.html to be an exception from redirecting mysite.com to www.mysite.com then you don't need this rule.

```
# Redirects www.mysite.com/exception.html to mysite.com/exception.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteRule ^exception.html$ http://%1/exception.html [R]
```

### Redirect mysite.com -> www.mysite.com

```
# Redirects mysite.com to www.mysite.com. We must add a condition to avoid an infinite redirect loop with exception.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(mysite\.com) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^exception.html$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: unfortunately both rules create a redirect loop :(

Comment: @NickZulu All right, so it sounds like the first RewriteRule matches which is good I guess :) It's very important that the rewrite condition that defines the exception in the second rule matches the exception URL (that means, this part: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^exception.html$`). Maybe you could specify exactly what the exception URL is, that can be helpful (feel free to obfuscate the domain etc as appropriately). BTW, I've replaced the `%{REQUEST_SCHEME}` variables with the literal **http** as it seems to be more stable.

Comment: @NickZulu No problem. Interesting that you marked Code-Source's answer :)

Comment: tight time schedules left me no space for further testing, Code-Source's answer was applied (marked as working) but with a small flaw...hope I had more time... :) thank you again!